# filter not working inside for loop in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to fetch data inside the for loop in my view.This is my code:

def func(request):

```
list = UserBookmark.objects.values('bookmark').filter(tag = "a")
print list
for i in list:
    print i
    tag_ids = UserBookmark.objects.values('tag').filter(bookmark = i)
    print tag_ids
return render(request,'index.html')
```

I am getting a value of i when i print i.Also i have records where bookmark = i
print i gives values like these:

```
  {u'bookmark': u'https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/cs101/lessons/48753036/concepts/487183640923'}
```

and when i run  this query in shell:

tag_ids = UserBookmark.objects.values('tag').filter(bookmark = 'https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/cs101/lessons/48753036/concepts/487183640923')

i get value for tag_ids too

but i am getting an empty query set in the for loop.This looks like some silly mistake but i am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.values()` method on a queryset gives a list of dictionary-like objects. Iterating over this list returns individual dictionaries. You are therefore trying to match inside the forloop that entire dictionary. It equates to something like

```
queryset.filter(
    bookmark={u'bookmark': u'http://www.example.com'}
)
```

---

Update: I was wrong about being able to use `.values()` on it. It's a list of dictionaries, not an individual dictionary.

Instead try:

```
for i in list:
    tag_ids = UserBookmark.objects.values('tag').filter(bookmark=i['bookmark'])
```

Comment: Oops, I was wrong. I've updated this above. Sorry for the misdirection.

Comment: What happens when you do `print(i['bookmark'])` inside the forloop? And does a simple query of `UserBookmark.objects.filter(bookmark='https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/cs101/lessons/48753036/concepts/487183640923')` work?